# Assign DataKey to Gridview using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I am currently using ajax to populate a gridview, I am populating the columns ok but I do not know how to assign the DataKey Via Javascript.

This is my ajax code

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/MemberPages/AdminPages/Roles.aspx/GetRoles",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var roles = data.d;
                $.each(roles, function (key, value) {
                    $("#<%=gvRoles.ClientID %>").append("<tr><td>" + value + "</td></tr>");
                });
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

I would like to set the key as the data key name

Comment: DataKeys don't go to the client. You will need to save them in a hidden field in every row to accomplish this.